# Filter By category select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a filter by category

my problem if I set in a data-attribute with (`cat1`, `cat2`)

it is not displayed

**1st solution :** I tried with include method but the problem I have two words in data-attribute

**2nd solution :** I tried with index of 
the problem in condition else he add  hidden for all div

```js
var ext = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat1"];

$("#ddlViewBy").on("change", function(e) {
  var name = $("#ddlViewBy option:selected").text();
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.full-image');
  divs.forEach(div => {
     div.classList.remove('hidden');
  });
  if (name == "Categorie") {
    divs.forEach(div => {
       length =ext.length;
      while(length--) {
   if (div.dataset['image'].indexOf(ext[length])!=-1) {
       div.classList.add("show");
   }
  else {
       div.classList.add("hidden");
   }

}

    });
  }

});
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">all</option>
  <option value="1">Categorie 1</option>

</select>
<div class="full-image" data-id="2" data-image="cat1">aa<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="3" data-image="cat1">bb<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="4" data-image="cat1">cc<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1 cat2">dd<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1,cat2">oo<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="6" data-image="cat1">ccs<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="7" data-image="cat1">yy<img src="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Did you missed `"Categorie 1"` from  `if (name == "Categorie")` or you purposefully added `if (name == "Categorie")`

Comment: you wrote `if (name == "Categorie") { ... }` but actually name is "Categorie 1"

Comment: Why are you trying to get the index of `ext[length]`? length is going to be (in this example) 4. You are never going to find the index of '4' in a string of "cat1 cat2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have the same value for all the options. You can add/remove a single class based on the currently selected value using *attribute ends with selector*.

Try the following way:

```js
$("#ddlViewBy").on("change", function(e) {
  var val = $("#ddlViewBy option:selected").val();
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.full-image');
  if(val == 'all') $('.full-image').removeClass('hidden');
  else{
    $('.full-image').addClass('hidden');
    $(`[data-image$=${val}]`).removeClass('hidden'); //notice use of template string using back tick (``)
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="cat1">Categorie 1</option>
  <option value="cat2">Categorie 2</option>
  <option value="cat3">Categorie 3</option>
</select>
<div class="full-image" data-id="2" data-image="cat1">aa<img src=""/></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="3" data-image="cat1">bb<img src=""/></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="4" data-image="cat1">cc<img src=""/></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1 cat2">dd<img src="" /></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1,cat2">oo<img src="" /></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="6" data-image="cat1">ccs<img src="" /></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="7" data-image="cat1">yy<img src="" /></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat3">c3<img src="" /></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="6" data-image="cat3">c33<img src="" /></div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="7" data-image="cat3">c333<img src="" /></div>
```

Comment: i have question if have  in option Categorie 2 , Categorie  3

Comment: @Thomas-anderson002anderson002, `Categorie 2` is already in the answer, similar way you can add `Categorie 3` as well:)

Comment: @Thomas-anderson002anderson002, updated the answer with `Categorie 3` sample data, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

I updated your example a bit. Explanations in the code

```js
$("#ddlViewBy").on("change", function(e) {
  // getting a select value could be '', '1', '2'
  const value = e.target.value;
  // getting all divs
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.full-image');
  // looping div
  divs.forEach(div => {
   // if value is empty (this means !value will be true)  than all divs should be visible
   // or, this or means than value is `1` or `2`, so in this case
   // if data-image includes `cat${value}` than display it
   if (!value || div.dataset.image.includes(`cat${value}`)) {
     div.classList.remove('hidden');
   } else { // otherwise - hide
     div.classList.add('hidden');
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="">all</option>
  <option value="1">Categorie 1</option>
  <option value="2">Categorie 2</option>
</select>
<div class="full-image" data-id="2" data-image="cat1">aa<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="3" data-image="cat1">bb<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="4" data-image="cat1">cc<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1 cat2">dd<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1,cat2">oo<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="6" data-image="cat1">ccs<img src="" />
</div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="7" data-image="cat1">yy<img src="" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much :) but in the all it's not work

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ext = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat1"];

$("#ddlViewBy").on("change", function(e) { 
  var name = $(this).val();
 if(name == "1"){
  $('.full-image').removeClass('hidden');
  return;
 }    
 $('.full-image').addClass('hidden');
 $('.full-image').each(function(){ 
  $(`[data-image*=${name}]`).removeClass('hidden');
 }); 

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlViewBy">
   <option value="1">all</option>
   <option value="cat1">Category 1</option> 
   <option value="cat2">Category 2</option> 
  </select>
  <div class="full-image" data-id="2" data-image="cat1">aa<img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="full-image" data-id="3" data-image="cat1">bb<img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="full-image" data-id="4" data-image="cat1">cc<img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1 cat2">dd<img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1,cat2">oo<img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="full-image" data-id="6" data-image="cat1">ccs<img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="full-image" data-id="7" data-image="cat1">yy<img src="" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

more simple to do in JS:

```js
const s_ddlViewBy = document.querySelector('#ddlViewBy')
  ,    s_divCat = document.querySelectorAll('.full-image')
  ;
s_ddlViewBy.oninput=_=>{
  let sCat = s_ddlViewBy.value ? 'cat'+s_ddlViewBy.value : ''
  s_divCat.forEach(elm=>{
    if (elm.dataset.image.includes(sCat)) { elm.classList.remove('hidden') }
    else                                  { elm.classList.add('hidden') }
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="">all</option>
  <option value="1">Categorie 1</option>
  <option value="2">Categorie 2</option>
</select>

<div class="full-image" data-id="2" data-image="cat1"     >--aa c1    <img src="" /> </div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="3" data-image="cat2"     >--bb c2    <img src="" /> </div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="4" data-image="cat1"     >--cc c1    <img src="" /> </div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1 cat2">--dd c1 c2 <img src="" /> </div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5" data-image="cat1,cat2">--oo c1 c2 <img src="" /> </div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="6" data-image=""         >--xx no cat<img src="" /> </div>
<div class="full-image" data-id="7" data-image="cat2"     >--yy c2    <img src="" /> </div>
```